# Approximating an infinite family of holomorphic functions by polynomials in relative error

Tags: cv.complex-variables, fourier-analysis, complex-manifolds

I *think* I just proved a theorem I haven't found in the literature, and I *think* it must generalize. I therefore have two questions. First, if this is in the literature, what is it called? Second, what sort of generalization is in the literature?

---

**Theorem.** Let $V \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a bounded open connected domain. Let $U \subset V$ be a compact subset of $V$. Let $e \geq 1$ be an integer. Let $v(z) : V \to \mathbb{C}^e$ be analytic. For $p \in \mathbb{C}^e$, define the function $f(z,p) = \sum_{k=1}^e p_k v_k(z)$. Then, there is an integer $m \geq 0$, constants $0 < c_1 \leq c_2 < \infty$ and a function $Q(z,p)$ such that:

1. For each $p \in \mathbb{C}^e$, the function $z \to Q(z,p)$ is a polynomial of degree $m$.
2. $c_1 |Q(z,p)| \leq |f(z,p)| \leq c_2 |Q(z,p)|$ for all $z\in U, p\in \mathbb{C}^e$.

---

The special case $e=1$ is maybe simplest to understand. In that case, the parameter $p$ goes away, and this theorem says that $f(z)$ can be approximated by a polynomial $Q(z)$ of degree $m$ within some *relative error*, which is different from the usual *absolute error* we get, e.g. from Taylor series truncation and remainder term. It also looks like Weierstrass factorization (which I learned about this week, don't judge!) Loosely speaking, if a function is an infinite product of $(z-z_k)$ terms, then you would get $Q(z)$ by dropping all but finitely many of those terms. The very important thing (for me) that my theorem says is that this approximation is uniform across an infinite family of analytic functions parametrized by $p$; I don't know if you can easily get that from Weierstrass.

The generalization I was thinking about is to discard $v(z)$ and instead assume directly that $f(z,p)$ is complex analytic in $(z,p)$. Because of what happens with complex analysis in several variables, I half expect this to swerve into Riemann manifolds, about which I know nothing.
In case it matters, the application is for Muckenhoupt weights.